# SQL OR clause to not read every row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there a better way in where clauses to do the following type of OR condition

```
WHERE (@TestID IS NULL OR t.[ID] = @TestID)
```

The problem I am having is there are many of these in the WHERE clause on different variables and it is causing huge numbers or reads. What I am trying to accomplish is if the parameter is NULL do not evaluate it, if it is not NULL then evaluate it. The only solution I have come up with so far is breaking these into huge queries checking what is populated and tailoring the queries like that:

```
IF @TestID IS NOT NULL
....

ELSE IF @TestID IS NULL
....
```

This becomes extremely cumbersome and hard to maintain with many variables.

Comment: This is worth reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/05/03/sometimes-the-simplest-solution-isn-t-the-best-solution-the-all-in-one-search-query.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's a good article, but there's a better way to grant permission in the dynamic sql case using certificates. See http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates

Comment: Here is an article that explains in detail a number of ways to deal with this type of catch all query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a lot of these, it might be a case for dynamic SQL, as this pattern of searching is prone to parameter sniffing problems.

```
create proc dbo.MySearch @col1 int, @col2 varchar(30) as

declare @sql nvarchar(max), @params nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'select col1, col2 from dbo.Table where 1 = 1';
set @params = '@col1 int, @col2 varchar(30)';

if @col1 is not null set @sql += 'and Col1 = @col1';
if @col2 is not null set @sql += 'and Col2 = @col2';

exec sp_executesql @sql, @params, @col1, @col2;
```

The real answer to managing the complexity, though, is to write a program to generate the stored procedure!

Answer (score 1):

```
Where ISNULL(t.[ID], @TestId) = @TestId
```

This will retrieve all null values and those matching your `TestId`